# Why is this simple CORS request doing a pre-flight options check

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, cors

I'm issuing a simple CORS request, to a cross-origin resource. I assumed as it is a POST request, with a parameter, it would classify as a simple CORS request, and therefore not need a pre-flight call. But it looks to not be the case.

Also, Unfortunately because I am using .NET Web API, any simple data-type has to be passed on the query string in a Post request.

Using angular $http for post.

OPTIONS:

```
Request URL:http://api.local.foundation.com/account/LoginAutomatically?key=null
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:api.local.foundation.com
Origin:http://www.local.foundation.com
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://www.local.foundation.com/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
key:null
```

POST:

```
Request URL:http://api.local.foundation.com/account/LoginAutomatically?key=null
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8
Host:api.local.foundation.com
Origin:http://www.local.foundation.com
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://www.local.foundation.com/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
key:null
```

Comment: The preflight OPTIONS request is necessary for all CORS.  The `Access-Control-*` headers are what the client looks for before proceeding.  A request is a request, no matter how 'simple'.

Comment: @danronmoon OPTIONS is not necessary for all of CORS.  It is only sent ahead of "non-simple" CORS requests.  The CORS spec defines a simple CORS request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your CORS request is preflighted due to the Content-Type of your request.  "application/json" makes your request a "non-simple" CORS request, thus it is preflighted.  If the Content-Type of your request was, say, "text/plain", it would not be preflighted in this case.

Comment: Oh thanks! So any request that wants json is non-simple? Is it safe to get text/plan back and assume it's json? I'd like to avoid pre flight requests where possible.

Comment: I don't see a problem with setting the Content-Type to "text/plain".  In fact, if you want to support cross-origin requests in older browsers (such as IE8 and IE9) you will not be able to set a Content-Type at all due to the limitations of the cross-origin transport mechanism in these browsers (`XDomainRequest`).  Keep in mind that, with "text/plain" as your Content-Type, your server framework will likely not parse the JSON in the response for you.

Comment: Another option is to send your data "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" or multipart encoded.  These Content-Types will also not trigger a preflight, and your server framework should be able to automatically parse the request body.